# Application server for Crystal web app / Kemal

Tags: crystal-lang

As Rails developer I'm used to Nginx + Unicorn in our servers.

Are there similar solutions for Crystal web apps / Kemal ?

I'm not a Nginx expert but I suppose I could use proxy_pass directly to the Crystal HTTP server or Kemal or fast-http-server... what I would miss is process management, GC options, re-spawing, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Nginx in front of your Kemal application and that's fine.

For process management and monitoring i suggest you use something like Monit, init.d e.g since it's not the responsibility of the app server.

Comment: Good tips. But there's also the multi process management / forking... something like Unicorn would be great

Comment: I'm trying with Nginx + Kemal as suggested by Serdar, with [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) for process supervision. Few options available but it seems fine for now